# When I install any npm package in window this error occur and can not install package properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

- bootstrap@4.1.1
  updated 1 package and audited 1932 packages in 17.046s

145 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 6 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 2 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete folder 'node_modules' and run in console:

```
npm install // or yarn install
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an error, this message is normal.

> 145 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details

This line is a donation call (not mandatory)

> found 6 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 2 high) run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details

This line informs you that some of your package.json modules have vulnerabilities. Run `npm audit` to view a list of them and the associated vulnerabilities.

If you run the mentioned command `npm audit fix`, it will try to automatically fix it for you by updating your package.json with new versions for these modules.

Answer (score 1):

Delete **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** after taht:

```sh
npm audit fix
```

```sh
npm install
```